# Use variables in value of apex switch statement

Tags: apex

When using a variable in value of switch statement, I get an error:

> Error: Field must be an enum reference

Apex code:

```java
static final String VALUE_ORANGES = 'Oranges';
String expr = 'Oranges';
switch on expr {
    when VALUE_ORANGES {
        System.debug('Oranges are $0.59 a pound.');
    }
    when else {
        System.debug('Sorry, we are out of ' + expr  +'.');
    }
}
```

Why this doesn't work, only option is to use enum?

---

To compare with other language, similar code works fine in JavaScript.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The switch statement works as it does in many (but not all) other languages, which is to say that, under the hood, the compiler optimizes the layout of the switch statement's bytecode so that it runs in fixed time (`O(1)`). This is one of the reasons that makes the switch statement more attractive than the if-then-else chain, which has to potentially evaluate every single value in the chain.

The tradeoff for this performance boost is that you cannot use variables, only literal values. If variables were allowed, it would change the switch's execution time to linear execution time `O(n)`, because the compiler would no longer be able to optimize the bytecode, which in turn would be mean that the more `when` branches you have, the longer it would take to evaluate the switch statement.

Comment: That is a great explanation @sfdcfox but still makes me wonder about using constants, which should pretty much similar to literals. Any idea if this is a limitation that might be relaxed in future?

Comment: @JefersonChaves Constants aren't actually "constant" in that sense (they are "final" variables, which are still allowed to be set once at run time). I don't think this would be a feature coming up in the future, given the nature of how it works. In fact, that's one reason why I'm doing some major refactors at work, to take advantage of switches.

Comment: yeah, it could work great with compile-time constants like C-style `#define` preprocessor...